# How to get kqy value pairs into MySQL variable?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create kind of a quality score for star ratings from different merchants. E.g. ebay, amazon. Running on MySQL 5.7.x

The table looks like this:

```
article_id | merchant_id | rating | ratings
123          1             5        120
124          2             4.5      29
```

Now the prodblem is that each merchant has a different amount of ratings. Amazon receives many more ratings then a small site. So there must be kind of a waighted average to reflect that. I am trying to determine if the rating on a page is a good and strong indication of a product quality.

The idea now is to get the avg amount of ratings per merchant first:

```
SET @ratings_avg = (SELECT avg(ratings)
FROM products
WHERE MERCHANT_ID = 2
AND ratings IS NOT NULL
AND ratings > 0);
```

Then calculate a quality with a waighted average from ratings_avg

```
 SELECT
   MERCHANT_ID,
   ARTICLE_ID,
   IF(RATINGS>0, 1.0865*LN(RATINGS), 0) * @ratings_avg 
 FROM products
```

This does not work as I would need a key value pair of ratings_avg and merchant_id. How could that be done?

Answer (score 0):

Use `GROUP BY` in a subquery to create the key-value pairing.

```
SELECT p.merchant_id, p.article_id,
        IF(p.ratings > 0, 1.0865 * LN(p.ratings), 0) * a.ratings_avg AS rating
FROM products AS p
JOIN (
    SELECT merchant_id, AVG(ratings) AS ratings_avg
    FROM products
    WHERE ratings IS NOT NULL and ratings > 0
    GROUP BY merchant_id
) AS a ON a.merchant_id = p.merchant_id
```